# Access violations on Windows 2008 VPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, memory, email-server

I'm running a Windows 2008 VPS with 2GB RAM. I'm trying to install hMailServer on the VPS but when I get to the "choose installation directory" dialog I get error messages that keep popping up and make it so that I cannot continue.

As soon as the dialog opens I get these two errors:

```
"Access violation at address 73F53560. Read of addresss 00000014."
"Access violation at address 73EEBE21. Read of addresss 00000018."
```

Once I close these it frees up again but as soon as I click "Browse.." (to choose the directory) I get the following errors repeatedly that reopen if I close them.

```
"Access violation at address 73F0E371. Read of address 00000014."
"Access violation at address 73F4A006. Read of address 00000000."
```

I have no idea how to fix these. I can't run memory diagnostics, I assume because it's a VPS and not an actual server.

Comment: I found a [similar question](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21316) on the hMailServer forums. Is that you?

Comment: Yes that was me, I forgot that I had posted this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to follow up on the error here:

Our service provider in the end changed us to a completely different VPS because they couldn't find the issue with hMailServer. Installed smooth on the new VPS so possibly a hardware fault.